# Does it matter what version of GL you use in LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm starting to go through tutorials on lwjgl at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQAYMkzy9rQ

I noticed that the tutorials use the following import

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
```

I believe this means that it uses GL 1.1, which is not the newest version of GL. What are the negatives of using this version instead using the newest? If I wanted to write my own game with lwjgl in the future, would I import the newest version of openGL? And, should I even be following this tutorial if it uses an old version of GL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not matter but newer versions are able to use newer features. You can read the wiki of OpenGL to see what new is added.
[Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/History_of_OpenGL#Summary_of_version_changes)

Comment: For a example I use blend in version 1, this does not change in later versions as its only API.